# How to Insert List into a combo box list grid in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I am trying to make a combo box list from database but unable to do that .

I want to insert database column items to my Combo box . How can I do that . Here is a picture of database.[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I0Li.png)
[Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDpug.png)

Comment: It has a Data source property. you can use for your purpose. insert your list into that property

Comment: farshad thanks but i am not clear what are you telling ?

Comment: you can retrieve your list and set it into => comboBox1.DataSource

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this problem Using this code .

```
private void subroutine(OracleCommand cmdTest) //add this kind of sub routine to page load .
    {
        //Getting table from database .
        StringBuilder sqlSel = new StringBuilder();
        sqlSel.AppendLine("SELECT");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("      MFP.NO");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFP.NAME");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFP.USER");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFP.DATE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFP.USER");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFP.DATE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFPP.START_DATE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFPP.END_DATE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("    , MFPP.PRICE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("FROM");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("      T_TABLE_1 MFP");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("LEFT JOIN");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("      T_TABLE_2" MFPP");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("ON");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("      MFP.NO = MFPP.NO"); //Number of two table must be same to connect these table .
        sqlSel.AppendLine("WHERE");
        sqlSel.AppendLine("      DELETE_STATUS = :DELETE_STATUS");

        cmdTest.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdTest.CommandText = sqlSel.ToString();
        cmdTest.BindByName = true;
        cmdTest.Parameters.Clear();

        cmdTest.Parameters.Add(":DELETE_STATUS", TestCldConst.DELETE_STATUS_USE);

        using (OracleDataReader drd = cmdTest.ExecuteReader())
        {
            try
            {
                using (DataTable dtb = new DataTable())
                {
                    dtb.Load(drd);

                    cmbBox.Items.Clear();
                    cmbBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtb.Rows)
                    {
                        cmbBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(row["NAME"]), Convert.ToString(row["NO"])));
                       }
                    control.SetPageSession(FuneralCostDetailHandler.SESSION_NAME_FUNERAL_PLAN, dtb);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                drd.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```